# Restricteddomainhelp.com

Tags: language-agnostic

if i run the my application...i am getting an message as restricteddomainhelp.com
and its not allowing me to open the page..

Comment: You have to clarify: what application are you trying to run? What language/platform? etc.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help you: http://windowsprotection.net/how-to-remove-restricteddomainhelpcom-hijacker-restricteddomainhelpcom-removal-guide/

Answer (score 0):

the link provided above requires us to buy the s/w.Is there any free tool to remove PAV

Comment: The link also includes instructions for manual removal. Search for the text "To perform manual removal of RestrictedDomainHelp.com hijacker, you should do the following:".